# Making a site fit the size of all screens(Center in middle of bigger screens)

Tags: html, css

Alright so I am working on a website and I did it on a lap top, so for bigger screens the left side is just the blank background color. I was hoping someone could inform me of a way to center the site on a bigger screen. Im open to any other ways of solving the screen problem though.

Comment: try using margin: auto;

Answer (score 0):

Usually this situation calls for margins, but the problem is that you can only set one margin. Try out the top, bottom, left, right attributes in CSS. By doing this, you can set how far you want the text to be from either the top, bottom,left, or right. Try getting a rough average of how big most devices are and set your measurements from there.

Answer (score 0):

So the traditionnal way to center a page content is through a container. Just give it a width (px, em, %, etc.) and side margins set to auto.

```css
.site{
  background: red;
}
.container{
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  <div class="container">
    Site content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is exactly what I am looking for! Now my problem is to implement it, lets just say how you would implement in its simplest form of a website. For example just a plain HTML document that in the body says "content" where in the HTML would I place <div class="site">
  <div class="container">
    Site content
  </div>
</div>

Comment: You would place the html of this example inside the <body> tag.